# R: trouble converting a list to dataframe using as.data.frame()

Tags: r

I seem to have problems converting a list to a dataframe in R. i used the following code to calculate a cumsum:

```
kaka_final <- kaka_final %>% group_by(id) %>% 
        mutate(cumCost = order_by(month, cumsum(cost)))
```

Worked perfect but returns a list and not a dataframe as i need in the next method. So i used the as.data.frame function but that doesn't seem to work either it still returns a list:

```
kaka_final <- as.data.frame(kaka_final %>% group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(cumCost = order_by(month, cumsum(cost)))) 
> 
> B <- as.data.frame(kaka_final)
> 
> typeof(kaka_final)
[1] "list"
> typeof(B)
[1] "list"
```

what am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example of `kaka_final`? You can use `dput(kaka_final)` for example..

Comment: The 1st instruction shouldn't return a list. `typeof` returns `list` for objects of class `data.frame`. Try `class(kaka_final)`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes it seems so. i'm sorry.

Comment: No problem, they're not always easy to find